# (Updated Question) If a race of creatures have unlimited time and resources what methods of architectural engineering would they use?

Tags: magic, architecture, engineering

Human architecture is driven by cost, time and ability to move and use certain materials. So what methods of architectural engineering would come to use if time, cost and materials had no limits?

---

**Culture:** The soul purpose of these creatures is to close Pandora's Box; everything they do is about capturing, incarcerating, and organizing reality back into the box. They are almost robotic in nature, orderly to a fault, reveling in hierarchy and organization.

**Biology:** At their core (akin to a heart) is a micro star, they feed off of this energy and do not need to eat or sleep, they are tireless and have no sense of time. Their appearance is still a WIP:

[image]

**Materials:** [Black Tourmaline](https://www.google.ca/search?q=black%20tourmaline&biw=1440&bih=810&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjinbOvg43PAhVhImMKHbLWDCkQ_AUIBigB) - [Raw Moissanite](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Moissanite-USGS-20-1001d-14x-.jpg/240px-Moissanite-USGS-20-1001d-14x-.jpg) - [Pink Corundum](https://img0.etsystatic.com/030/0/5798979/il_570xN.554381042_fbdl.jpg) - Gold - [Neutronium](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg20928026-900-eight-extremes-the-densest-thing-in-the-universe/)

Either extremely hard, dense, inert, rare or a combination. This also follows their color scheme of glossy black, pink/purple gradients and gold trimming.

**Technology** - Highly advanced, the universe could be their canvas if not for their culture.

Comment: I can't imagine what the thumbs down are for.  This is a very interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

**Pop-tents and Legos**

At first when I read the question I thought maybe they would choose a building material that would last forever, or at least something inert like glass.

Then I remembered how often people I know go about renovating their houses and apartments. Humans tend to get board with their surrounding and like to change them. So maybe they would use an easily manipulated material, or at least something that can be easily removed/replaced. Something along the lines of interlocking plastic wall segments. Almost like gigantic Legos or building blocks for grownups.

Then I finished reading your description of your race, and their single minded goal of closing Pandora’s box. It sounds like they wouldn’t care what they ‘lived’ in. from your short description they might live a minimal life living in the equivalent of space age popup tents. Something functional, and not really decorative.

I have the feeling if more than a handful are living in one area then they probably are not efficiently distributing themselves enough to complete their goal. With so few in one area they would not need anything extensive like sky scrappers. They might have a need to store some of the stuff they “incarcerated” This would call for a larger building, maybe something  along the lines of a popup warehouse made for the gigantic lego walls I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You're quite right the only large buildings would be for storage, malleable legos is an interesting idea. I had the same train of thought there wouldn't be any decoration, minimal form all function which is why I'm so interested in the engineering side of things.